# Is there a way for the system to "ignore" an alleged wifi-bluetooth hardware block?

Tags: networking, xubuntu, bluetooth

According to rfkill, my Bluetooth (and Wi-Fi) devices are "blocked by hardware". Nonetheless, bluetooth is functional, when connected to a device.

This is what appears when there are no active connections to the bluetooth.

[image]

This is what appears when I turn on the bluetooth speaker and it gets automatically connected:

[image]

Although, I can't open the bluetooth device manager because for the system, the bluetooth "is turned off".

[image]

But it is actually ON and CONNECTED. I can't connect new devices neither can I send files from the laptop to the connected devices.

I am no expert but I think this is *a bug in the system* that is telling it that the Bluetooth is OFF, or hard-blocked, when it actually isn't. And I also think, something similar is happening with the Wi-Fi (my real concern) because it is also telling the system that "it is disabled" when it shouldn't be.

This is the rfkill input:

```
rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE              SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      sony-wifi      unblocked   blocked
 1 bluetooth sony-bluetooth unblocked   blocked
 2 bluetooth hci0           unblocked unblocked
 3 wlan      phy0           unblocked unblocked
```

PS: There have been some days when I have turned on the laptop and both bluetooth and wifi worked fine...

Some people suggest it is probably a hardware problem with the device. But it all started after I upgraded Xubuntu 22.04 to 22.10. Unfortunately, I am currently unable to "test a live session" of other Linux distribution.

*Is there a way for the system to "ignore" that alleged hardware block?*

Comment: You may want to file a bug report. https://ubuntu.com/blog/the-keys-to-successful-bug-reporting

Comment: thank you @user535733. I have already checked in the BIOS settings and there's nothing related to wifi. I don't know if all BIOS are the same or if they depend on the laptop vendor, version, year, etc... Also, there's a physical button to turn on/off the wireless functions preset in this laptop (VAIO) that is and has always been ON.

Comment: PS: I would also like to add that this problem has been happening since I upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10, and in-between the times I have finished working with the laptop and turned it off, a few times when I have turned it back on the next day, all wifi and bluetooth were working fine. But then again, they become "hard-blocked" again after another turning off and on.

Comment: @user535733 but my question remains, If bluetooth is currently shown as disabled by the system, hard-blocked, according to rfkill, if I can't open the device manager because the bluetooth is turned off (according to the system) then, how come when I turn on any bluetooth device that was already peered, it gets connected? And, the system continues to inform by any means (rfkill and trying to open the device manager) that bluetooth if OFF, when it is ON and connected to a device.

Comment: Well, if you are sure you have no faulty hardware, and you are sure that Ubuntu is responsible, then file a bug report like @David recommended.